# How to put a photo to those questions

Tags: javascript, html, css

When it runs the code shows random questions, but I would also like it to show me a picture on those questions. And make it work for a cell phone.
Can you help me with this code? I couldn't do it myself, I tried but it's complicated, I want all the questions to show me a photo.
For example: that each question has a different image.

It could be done?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#remaining-time").hide();
  $("#start").on("click", trivia.startGame);
  $(document).on("click", ".option", trivia.guessChecker);
});

var trivia = {
    correct: 0,
    incorrect: 0,
    unanswered: 0,
    currentSet: 0,
    // "seen" property will keep track of the seen questions so we don't re-display them again
    seen: [],
    // Update: limit the number of question per game. Usong a property so you can change its value whenever you want to change the limit
    limit: 4,
    timer: 20,
    timerOn: false,
    timerId: "",
    // questions options and answers data
//I would like the image to adapt with each question asked
    questions: {
      q1: "Who is actually a chef?",
      q2: "What does Joey love to eat?",
      q3: "How many times has Ross been divorced?",
      q4: "How many types of towels does Monica have?",
      q5: "Who stole Monica's thunder after she got engaged?",
      q6: "Who hates Thanksgiving?",
      q7: "Who thinks they're always the last to find out everything?"
    },
//very long responses don't fit in the container, so I want it to fit the cell phone
    options: {
      q1: ["Monica", "Chandler", "Rachel", "Rosssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss"],
      q2: ["Fish", "Apples", "Oranges", "Sandwhiches"],
      q3: ["5", "2", "1", "3"],
      q4: ["3", "8", "11", "6"],
      q5: ["Rachel", "Phoebe", "Emily", "Carol"],
      q6: ["Joey", "Chandler", "Rachel", "Rosssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss"],
      q7: ["Ross", "Phoebe", "Monica", "Chandlerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr"]
    },
    answers: {
      q1: "Monica",
      q2: "Sandwhiches",
      q3: "3",
      q4: "11",
      q5: "Rachel",
      q6: "Chandler",
      q7: "Phoebe"
    },
    // random number generator
    random: (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min,
    startGame: function() {
      trivia.currentSet = 0;
      // set "seen" to an empty array for a new game
      trivia.seen = [];
      trivia.correct = 0;
      trivia.incorrect = 0;
      trivia.unanswered = 0;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      $("#game").show();
      $("#results").html("");
      $("#timer").text(trivia.timer);
      $("#start").hide();
      $("#remaining-time").show();
      trivia.nextQuestion();
    },
    nextQuestion: function() {
      trivia.timer = 10;
      $("#timer").removeClass("last-seconds");
      $("#timer").text(trivia.timer);
      if (!trivia.timerOn) {
        trivia.timerId = setInterval(trivia.timerRunning, 1000);
      }
      // get all the questions
      const qts = Object.values(trivia.questions);
      // init the random number
      let rq = null;
      // firstly, if no more questions to show set rq to -1 to let us know later that the game has finished 
      // Update: checking if we reached the "limit"
      if (trivia.seen.length >= trivia.limit) rq = -1
      else {
        // otherwise generate a random number from 0 inclusive to the length of the questions - 1 (as array indexing starts from 0 in JS) also inclusive
        do {
          // generate a random number using the newly added "random" method
          rq = trivia.random(0, qts.length - 1);
        } while (trivia.seen.indexOf(rq) != -1); // if the question is already seen then genrate another number, do that till we get a non-seen question index
        // add that randomly generated index to the seen array so we know that we have already seen it
        trivia.seen.push(rq);
        // increment the counter
        trivia.counter++;
      }
      // current question index is the generated random number "rq"
      trivia.currentSet = rq;
      var questionContent = Object.values(trivia.questions)[rq];
      $("#question").text(questionContent);
      var questionOptions = Object.values(trivia.options)[trivia.currentSet];
      $.each(questionOptions, function(index, key) {
        $("#options").append(
          $('<button class="option btn btn-info btn-lg">' + key + "</button>")
        );
      });
    },
    timerRunning: function() {
      if (
        trivia.timer > -1 &&
        // all the questions have already been seen
        // Update: now we check against the limit property
        trivia.seen.length < trivia.limit
    ) {
      $("#timer").text(trivia.timer);
      trivia.timer--;
      if (trivia.timer === 4) {
        $("#timer").addClass("last-seconds");
      }
    } else if (trivia.timer === -1) {
      trivia.unanswered++;
      trivia.result = false;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
      $("#results").html(
        "<h3>Out of time! The answer was " +
        Object.values(trivia.answers)[trivia.currentSet] +
        "</h3>"
      );
    }
    // if the game ended as we know that -1 means no more questions to display
    else if (trivia.currentSet === -1) {
      $("#results").html(
        "<h3>Thank you for playing!</h3>" +
        "<p>Correct: " +
        trivia.correct +
        "</p>" +
        "<p>Incorrect: " +
        trivia.incorrect +
        "</p>" +
        "<p>Unaswered: " +
        trivia.unanswered +
        "</p>" +
        "<p>Please play again!</p>"
      );
      $("#game").hide();
      $("#start").show();
    }
  },
  guessChecker: function() {
    var resultId;
    var currentAnswer = Object.values(trivia.answers)[trivia.currentSet];
    if ($(this).text() === currentAnswer) {
      //turn button green for correct
      $(this).addClass("btn-success").removeClass("btn-info");
      trivia.correct++;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
      $("#results").html("<h3>Correct Answer!</h3>");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("btn-danger").removeClass("btn-info");

      trivia.incorrect++;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
      $("#results").html(
        "<h3>Better luck next time! " + currentAnswer + "</h3>"
      );
    }
  },

  guessResult: function() {
    // no need to increment trivia.currentSet anymore
    $(".option").remove();
    $("#results h3").remove();
    trivia.nextQuestion();
  }
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header text-center clearfix">
    <h1 class="text-muted">Friends trivia game</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="game">
        <h2>FRIENDS Trivia Game</h2>
        <p id="remaining-time" class="lead">Remaining Time: <span id="timer"></span></p>
        <p id="question" class="lead"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="results">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div id="choices" class="text-center">
        <button id="start" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Start Game</button>
        <div id="options">

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#remaining-time").hide()
  $("#start").on("click", trivia.startGame)
  $(document).on("click", ".option", trivia.guessChecker)
})

const images = [
  "https://careerbright.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/chef-career-800x483.png",

  "https://careerbright.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/chef-career-800x483.png",

  "https://careerbright.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/chef-career-800x483.png",

  "https://careerbright.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/chef-career-800x483.png",

  "https://careerbright.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/chef-career-800x483.png",

  "https://careerbright.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/chef-career-800x483.png",

  "https://careerbright.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/chef-career-800x483.png",
]

var trivia = {
  correct: 0,
  incorrect: 0,
  unanswered: 0,
  currentSet: 0,
  // "seen" property will keep track of the seen questions so we don't re-display them again
  seen: [],
  // Update: limit the number of question per game. Usong a property so you can change its value whenever you want to change the limit
  limit: 4,
  timer: 20,
  timerOn: false,
  timerId: "",
  // questions options and answers data
  //I would like the image to adapt with each question asked
  questions: {
    q1: "Who is actually a chef?",
    q2: "What does Joey love to eat?",
    q3: "How many times has Ross been divorced?",
    q4: "How many types of towels does Monica have?",
    q5: "Who stole Monica's thunder after she got engaged?",
    q6: "Who hates Thanksgiving?",
    q7: "Who thinks they're always the last to find out everything?",
  },
  //very long responses don't fit in the container, so I want it to fit the cell phone
  options: {
    q1: [
      "Monica",
      "Chandler",
      "Rachel",
      "Rosssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss",
    ],
    q2: ["Fish", "Apples", "Oranges", "Sandwhiches"],
    q3: ["5", "2", "1", "3"],
    q4: ["3", "8", "11", "6"],
    q5: ["Rachel", "Phoebe", "Emily", "Carol"],
    q6: [
      "Joey",
      "Chandler",
      "Rachel",
      "Rosssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss",
    ],
    q7: [
      "Ross",
      "Phoebe",
      "Monica",
      "Chandlerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr",
    ],
  },
  answers: {
    q1: "Monica",
    q2: "Sandwhiches",
    q3: "3",
    q4: "11",
    q5: "Rachel",
    q6: "Chandler",
    q7: "Phoebe",
  },
  // random number generator
  random: (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min,
  startGame: function() {
    trivia.currentSet = 0
    // set "seen" to an empty array for a new game
    trivia.seen = []
    trivia.correct = 0
    trivia.incorrect = 0
    trivia.unanswered = 0
    clearInterval(trivia.timerId)
    $("#game").show()
    $("#results").html("")
    $("#timer").text(trivia.timer)
    $("#start").hide()
    $("#remaining-time").show()
    trivia.nextQuestion()
  },
  nextQuestion: function() {
    trivia.timer = 10
    $("#timer").removeClass("last-seconds")
    $("#timer").text(trivia.timer)
    if (!trivia.timerOn) {
      trivia.timerId = setInterval(trivia.timerRunning, 1000)
    }
    // get all the questions
    const qts = Object.values(trivia.questions)

    // init the random number
    let rq = null
    // firstly, if no more questions to show set rq to -1 to let us know later that the game has finished
    // Update: checking if we reached the "limit"
    if (trivia.seen.length >= trivia.limit) rq = -1
    else {
      // otherwise generate a random number from 0 inclusive to the length of the questions - 1 (as array indexing starts from 0 in JS) also inclusive
      do {
        // generate a random number using the newly added "random" method
        rq = trivia.random(0, qts.length - 1)

        // SHow the picture according to the question:
        const image = images[rq]
        const imageHtml = document.getElementById("image")
        imageHtml.src = image
        console.log(imageHtml.src)
      } while (trivia.seen.indexOf(rq) != -1) // if the question is already seen then genrate another number, do that till we get a non-seen question index
      // add that randomly generated index to the seen array so we know that we have already seen it
      trivia.seen.push(rq)
      // increment the counter
      trivia.counter++
    }
    // current question index is the generated random number "rq"
    trivia.currentSet = rq
    var questionContent = Object.values(trivia.questions)[rq]
    $("#question").text(questionContent)
    var questionOptions = Object.values(trivia.options)[trivia.currentSet]
    $.each(questionOptions, function(index, key) {
      $("#options").append(
        $('<button class="option btn btn-info btn-lg">' + key + "</button>")
      )
    })
  },
  timerRunning: function() {
    if (
      trivia.timer > -1 &&
      // all the questions have already been seen
      // Update: now we check against the limit property
      trivia.seen.length < trivia.limit
    ) {
      $("#timer").text(trivia.timer)
      trivia.timer--
        if (trivia.timer === 4) {
          $("#timer").addClass("last-seconds")
        }
    } else if (trivia.timer === -1) {
      trivia.unanswered++
        trivia.result = false
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId)
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000)
      $("#results").html(
        "<h3>Out of time! The answer was " +
        Object.values(trivia.answers)[trivia.currentSet] +
        "</h3>"
      )
    }
    // if the game ended as we know that -1 means no more questions to display
    else if (trivia.currentSet === -1) {
      $("#results").html(
        "<h3>Thank you for playing!</h3>" +
        "<p>Correct: " +
        trivia.correct +
        "</p>" +
        "<p>Incorrect: " +
        trivia.incorrect +
        "</p>" +
        "<p>Unaswered: " +
        trivia.unanswered +
        "</p>" +
        "<p>Please play again!</p>"
      )
      $("#game").hide()
      $("#start").show()
    }
  },
  guessChecker: function() {
    var resultId
    var currentAnswer = Object.values(trivia.answers)[trivia.currentSet]
    if ($(this).text() === currentAnswer) {
      //turn button green for correct
      $(this).addClass("btn-success").removeClass("btn-info")
      trivia.correct++
        clearInterval(trivia.timerId)
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000)
      $("#results").html("<h3>Correct Answer!</h3>")
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("btn-danger").removeClass("btn-info")

      trivia.incorrect++
        clearInterval(trivia.timerId)
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000)
      $("#results").html(
        "<h3>Better luck next time! " + currentAnswer + "</h3>"
      )
    }
  },

  guessResult: function() {
    // no need to increment trivia.currentSet anymore
    $(".option").remove()
    $("#results h3").remove()
    trivia.nextQuestion()
  },
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header text-center clearfix">
      <h1 class="text-muted">Friends trivia game</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        <div id="game">
          <h2>FRIENDS Trivia Game</h2>
          <p id="remaining-time" class="lead">
            Remaining Time: <span id="timer"></span>
          </p>
          <p id="question" class="lead"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="results"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div id="choices" class="text-center">
          <button id="start" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Start Game</button>
          <div id="options"></div>
        </div>
        <img src="" alt="" id="image" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /container -->
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

You can use something called Maps, let's say each question has a unique picture, and you have to get the picture the random question is `questions.q1` and you want to show a picture according to the question.
you could say:
`let pictures = new Map() pictures.set('q1', 'question1.png')` 
and whenever you want to retreive the picture you write:
`pictures.get('q1')` 
check out this link for more info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

And about the mobile issue, you have to use something called media query in CSS, so according to a screen size the styling can change, you can edit the width or the height of a container to make it resposive, check out this W3SCHOOLS link for more info:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

here is the code just run it and it will make the picutre appear, you can change the link of the picutres according to the questions, for example the 2nd picture has the link of the 2nd quesion and so on...

Comment: I couldn't do it, I already tried it and it didn't work, let pictures = new Map() pictures.set('q1', 'question1.png')

Comment: Did you change the path of the picture using javascript and pointing the image path ?

Comment: yes i did but it didn't work. You can upload your code @Yasser Goumghar

Comment: ok no problem but i don't use Jquery, so the code will be in vannila javascript

Answer (score 1):

Did you try creating another object that holds the pictures, like:

```
images: {
  q1: "https://i.imgur.com/5hu2QWu.jpg",
  q2: "https://i.imgur.com/03TKQxH.png",
```

...
},

And then displaying them before or after the options?

Another option I would consider, is changing the data format to something like:

```
var data = [
   { question: 'Question 1', options: ['opqion 1:1', 'option 1:2', ], image: 'imgUrl', correctOption: 1 }, 
   { question: 'Question 2', options: ['opqion 2:1', 'option 2:2', ], image: 'imgUrl', correctOption: 0 }, 
    ....
   ]
```

And that might be easier to display.

Comment: I already tried doing it that way but it didn't work

Comment: you can please.

Comment: @JairoLopez perdon por asumir, pero obvio no voy a lograr poner todo el codigo junto, si lo sigues pidiendo de esa forma los moderadores van a flag tu pregunta y borrarla. tienes que seguir intentando, o no se, meterte en uno de esos foros para principiantes. pero stack overflow no esta diseñado para eso. Trata por ejemplo https://www.codebuddies.org/